# What is the purpose of vendor/bundle? Heroku tells me to remove it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

Upon pushing some changes to Heroku, I noticed a warning about `vendor/bundle` (see **WARNING** below).

What is the purpose of this directory if, according to the warning, it should be "removed" from Git tracking?

Why isn't `vendor/bundle` automatically `.gitignore`'d by default by Rails?

Should I run `bundle pack`? (Is it actually `bundle package`??)

What are the pros and cons around `bundle pack` (relative to both `development` and `production`)?

To make this even more confusing, there's a popular blog post, by Ryan McGeary, titled ["Vendor Everything" Still Applies](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/02/09/vendor-everything-still-applies/) that strongly argues for running `bundle install --path vendor` and `echo 'vendor/ruby' >> .gitignore` and packaging gems in `vendor/cache` by running `bundle package`. Any light shed on this relative to my other concerns would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
-bash> git push production master
...

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> WARNING:  Removing `vendor/bundle`.
       Checking in `vendor/bundle` is not supported. Please remove this directory
       and add it to your .gitignore. To vendor your gems with Bundler, use
       `bundle pack` instead.
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.1
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Using rake (0.9.2.2)
       Using i18n (0.6.0)
       ...
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you have the `vendor/bundle` directory in your project then at some point [you must have run the `bundle` command with the `--path vendor/bundle` argument](https://bundler.io/v2.1/man/bundle-install.1.html). This will load the files for all your project's gems (listed in `Gemfile`) into the `vendor/bundle` directory in your local project rather than to a system gem location. You would do this to completely isolate a project's gems from any other project.

Bundler is good at resolving all dependencies so it isn't necessary to use the `--path` but some people choose to do so as they wish to keep their gems separate and organised with their project. It also means that bundler on your local machine is set up the same way that Heroku uses bundler.

With this option you are still downloading all gems from the [`rubygems`](https://rubygems.org/) servers every time you run the `bundle` command.

[`bundle package`](http://gembundler.com/bundle_package.html) takes it a step further and actually downloads the original gem files from `rubygems` and caches them into the `vendor/cache` directory. This means that you no longer need a connection to `rubygems` to run the bundle command as it will use the packaged files as the source. If you need to update a gem version then it will need to connect to `rubygems` to collect the new version the first time it is requested. Using `bundle package` will of course require additional disc space which may or may not be an issue depending on the situation. It would also increase deploy time and bandwidth requirements every time you pushed to Heroku.

Heroku runs the `bundle` command every time you `git push`, reading your `Gemfile.lock` and installing the gems required for the application to work. By default the `--path vendor/bundle` option is used. This is so that each application has a set of gem files separate from all other apps on Heroku. If you have the `vendor/bundle` directory in your source control and you push it to Heroku then you can see that there is the potential for significant conflict as it then attempts to load gems into `vendor/bundle` directory which already exists. If it is pushed then Heroku removes the `vendor/bundle` directory before it runs `bundle install` to remove these potential conflicts. If this is the case then you will be wasting deploy time and bandwidth by leaving `vendor/bundle` under version control, it's better to add it to your `.gitignore`.

If you want complete control over your gems on Heroku then use the `bundle package` command and make sure that the `vendor/cache` directory is under source control. When Heroku runs `bundle install` it will use the contents of `vendor/cache` as the gem source rather than using `rubygems`. Whether this is useful or not will be a matter of personal preference, the type of app that you are building and how often you update your gems. The Ryan McGeary post suggests that using `bundle package` is useful in case an old gem becomes unavailable at some point in the future. This would appear to be a bigger issue to projects/apps which are not regularly kept up to date.

From my perspective, I generally use `--path vendor/bundle` to keep my local setup as close as possible to Heroku's. I put `vendor/bundle` into my project's `.gitignore` file, and I don't *package* gems, as my projects are updated relatively regularly.

Rails has a very limited `.gitignore` file. You are effectively expected to build up what you need yourself, which is why `vendor/bundle` is not included by default.

I assume that Heroku means `bundle package` when they say `bundle pack`.

Comment: If you want to keep all of your gems system wide (which I like to do), be sure to take a look at your `~/.bundle/config` file to make sure it doesn't have any options which are forcing your gems to be installed into `/vendor/bundle`.

Comment: @varatis, You mean `.bundle/config` in the project root, no? Lifesaver, though. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure... I think I had a global gemset in which case (I believe) it would be `~/.bundle/config`, not in a project directory.

Comment: Thanks. How can I undo the --path /vendor/bundle? My app size has grown considerably since now Ruby is in vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0 and all gems are now inside that gems/ folder

Comment: @Ryan I removed the `./.bundle/config` file in my project root, and now `bundle install` no longer creates the `./vendor/bundle` directory.

Comment: "Using bundle package [...] would also increase deploy time and bandwidth requirements every time you pushed to Heroku."

It's hard to say if it really would unless we benchmark. The git repo would have a larger size but that only matters whenever a `git push` includes changes to `vendor/cache`. On the other hand, having all your gems in `vendor/cache` makes `bundle install` run faster.

Comment: _"I assume that Heroku means `bundle package` when they say `bundle pack`"_

Yes, `bundle pack` is an older shorthand (now just an alias) for `bundle package`.