# Could not find multi_json-1.7.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I am getting this error when pushing to my heroku staging environment.

Other related questions to this say to bundle update multi-json or to bundle update or remove Gemfile.lock and bundle install (which are all the same). None of these solutions worked for me.

my gemfile does not call multi-json
I tried specifying a version of multi-json but always encountered the same problem when deploying to heroku. My dev environment works fine.

I also updated bundler to 1.3.6 and tried everything again

```
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
   Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
   Could not find multi_json-1.7.2 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Comment: I'm grabbing at straws here, but the first thing I'd try is a `heroku restart`.

Comment: Another idea: it sounds like you may not have a Heroku staging server. Maybe you just have your local dev environment and then production. I'd be curious to see if you could spin up a Heroku staging server and successfully deploy there.

Comment: Any chance that the source definition in your Gemfile is other than `source 'https://rubygems.org'`?

Comment: I have a staging environment and the same error is happening in production. And the source is the same as you said    source 'https://rubygems.org'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was that because vendor/cache was present, it was looking for multi_json in that folder. I just deleted it and pushed and it is working.

this question helped

[What is the purpose of vendor/bundle? Heroku tells me to remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573596/what-is-the-purpose-of-vendor-bundle-heroku-tells-me-to-remove-it)