# Issue with install xcode while installing ruby, rails and postgresql on macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, apple-m1, bcrypt-ruby, xcode-command-line-tools

**UPDATES**

I'm having some issues on a new mac m1 and my install of ruby, rails, xcode and postgresql

#### First attempt:

##What I did ?

Installing homebrew, ruby, rails, postgresql

**OS**:  macOS Big Sur Version 11.2.1 (20D74)

**zsh**: 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)

**postgres**: 13.2

**Rails version**:  Rails 6.1.3

**Ruby version**: ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [arm64-darwin20]

**Brew version**:  Homebrew 3.0.9

## What I could do:

I have successfully:

- create a rails app with `rails new myApp -d postgresql`
- add gem devise to the Gemfile
- run `bundle install`
- create devise User and all CRUD views
- run `db:create`, `db:migrate`
- launch the server with `rails s`
- access all the pages of login, sign up, etc...

#### Expected behavior

I'm expecting to be able to create an account and connect to it on the app.

#### Actual behavior

When I try to create an account I'm running into an error about the gem bcrypt that seems to run on the wrong architecture...

#### Second attempt:

I've uninstall ruby, rails, rbenv, postgresql, homebrew

I've update my OS version to: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

I'm following this tutorial:
gorails.com/setup/osx/11.0-big-sur

**Brew version**:  Homebrew 3.0.11

**rbenv version**:  rbenv 1.1.2

**ruby versions**:

- 2.7.2 (set by /Users/lucas-illiano/.ruby-version)
  3.0.0 (I can't put the 3.0.0 version to global...)

**rails version**: 6.1.1

1. I've deleted rbenv before deleting all ruby versions on the system ? Is that why ?

At the end of the tutorial, before installing postgresql, it says to install this package `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

But I'm running into an issue about x-code and CommandLineTools install.

I've tried to download the package from here developer.apple.com/download/more I cannot get the folder `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

I've also tried `xcode-select --install` but x-code is already well install. No upgrade available.

I can't think of any other way to install successfully this package.

Anyone have an idea about the issue installing xcode and CommandLineTools on MacOS Big Sur?

Thanks by advance and have a good day to you all.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've tried to reinstall everything"? What is **everything**, and how did you reinstall it? Also, please try to avoid posting images in the question, unless it's absolutely the best way to describe something (e.g. a CSS layout question.) In your instance, *the most important text in your question* is actually in the image (!!), which says "No suitable image found. Did find: mach-o, but wrong architecture".

Comment: You're most likely going to be running into quite a lot of issues running Ruby with ARM64 as many of the libraries it depends on are playing catchup. You really want to consider installing Ruby in Rosetta 2 (Apples x86 compatiblity layer) to preserve your sanity for the time being. https://www.lewis8s.codes/ruby/programming/apple/arm/arm64/2020/11/27/how-to-install-ruby-on-apple-silicon.html

Comment: Another question is why the gem is located in `vendor/bundle`. Did you actually intend to do that or did someone forget to add the directory to `.gitignore`? This would explain why doing `bundle uninstall bcrypt` - `bundle install bcrypt` doesn't actually fix the  problem as gems in `vendor/bundle` will override your other gems. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573596/what-is-the-purpose-of-vendor-bundle-heroku-tells-me-to-remove-it

Comment: @TomLord @max
I have reinstall homebrew, rbenv and postgresql.
I'm folling this tutorial now: 
https://gorails.com/setup/osx/11.0-big-sur
I was able to reinstall ruby 2.7.2 and 3.0.0


`
rbenv versions
2.7.2 (set by /Users/lucas-illiano/.ruby-version)
3.0.0
`

not sure why but i can't set 3.0.0 to global.

I also install rails 6.1.1

On the tutorial they advise to install xcode commandlinetools
I've tried to download the package from here https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
I cannot get the folder `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

Comment: I've tried `xcode-select --install` but x-code is already well install. No upgrade available.

As I've read, the installation of the package `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`might resolve further problem about the pg gem.
I've just upgrade my os to macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
I can't think of any other way to install successfully this package.
Anyone have a tips ? Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you. If you were able to run the server then xcode, and other things are probably good already.

I am not much into Ruby/Rails now but from what I understand. Some gems are not supported for Apple M1 arch yet. If you're getting an error similar to `missing compatible arch` then using `arch -arch x86_64` before the command may help.

In my case, where I was running another gem - Jekyll, using `arch -arch x86_64` solved my problem.

```
> bundle exec jekyll build --> failed with arch error
```

But,

```
> arch -arch x86_64 bundle exec jekyll build --> works just fine
```